# Cant run pod install in windows for react native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

[image: c]

I have already installed cocoapods and ruby but still dont get what i m doing wrong can somebody lease help me.
I m using it for navigation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Running `pod install` is only required when running the iOS version of the app: `npx react-native run-ios`. The iOS version can only be run using a macbook or mac.

The android dependencies will be configured using the auto-linking. Any other iOS related action like running or building will have to happen on a device running macOS.